# If/When use "Azure Session State Provider (redis)" No need to use User.Identity.Name/IsAuthenticated?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, cloud, session-state

After we have moved to Azure farm, I have implied Azure Session State Provider (redis) to my asp.net mvc application, But some Authorized pages redirect me to login page !!
Is that because I use User.Identity.Name or User.Identity.IsAuthenticated in some actions!!
Do I have to replace the User.Identity.Name with :

```
       // instead of below line
      //Boolean usern = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
      // is below lines :
        Boolean usern = "";
        object objValue = Session["usersession"];
        if (objValue != null)
           { usern = true;}
        else {usern = false;}
```

Is that right, if not why users redirect to login again sometimes !!!

Comment: In other words, Is Redis azure session imply it self for membership provider, so when get User.Identity.Name  comes from Redis session!

Comment: Have you defined your machine key in your web.config?

Comment: Tommy, Please add your comment as an answer

Answer (score 4):

This is probably not a session issue but rather an authentication cookie/ticket issue.  Azure most likely has their servers load balanced, even if you are only using a single instance/role(this gives them reliability %).  Meaning that your application actually exists on more than one server at a time.

The MachineKey in a .NET app is what is responsible for encrypting and decrypting your authentication cookie.  In your web.config, if you are not properly defining the `<machineKey>` attribute, then IIS makes up a machine key for you.  Each server running the application will make their own machine key if it is not defined by you.  As a result, one server is able to decrypt and read your authentication ticket, while the next request goes to another server which cannot decrypt the authentication ticket because it was encrypted with a different key and this server thinks that you are not logged in.

To address this issue, open your web.config file and define your `<machineKey>` attribute and redeploy.  Once you login with the newly deployed application, you should see this issue disappear.

[Forms authentication and Machine Key information on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx#paght000007_webfarmdeploymentconsiderations)

[Machine Key Generator](http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the session management would do this, regardless of Azure Redis or otherwise.  If you are using asp.net authentication cookies you need to make changes to support multiple roles.

I know this is an old article but if you look through [Moving Applications to Microsoft Azure Cloud Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff803371.aspx) you will see this:

> There is one further change to the application that potentially
>   affects the authentication process. If you were to run the aExpense
>   application on more than one web role instance in Azure, the default
>   cookie encryption mechanism (which uses DPAPI) is not appropriate
>   because each instance has a different key. This would mean that a
>   cookie created by one web role instance would not be readable by
>   another web role instance. To solve this problem you should use a
>   cookie encryption mechanism that uses a key shared by all the web role
>   instances. The following code from the Global.asax file shows how to
>   replace the default SessionSecurityHandler object and configure it to
>   use the RsaEncryptionCookieTransform class.

essentially if this is happening the redirects to the login page are because you are bouncing to a different instance and it could not read the asp.net auth cookie and just assumed the user was not authenticated as a result.